# Why does the following code always print the timeout before the immediate?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does the following always appear:

0

...

999

Inside the timeout

Inside the immediate

Shouldn't the setImmediate have precedence in the callback queue?

```
setImmediate(()=>{
    console.log('Inside the immediate');
});

setTimeout(()=> {
    console.log('Inside the timeout');
}, 1);

for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: First it’s not recommended to use in a prod setting.  Second, per the docs it does not get priority.    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate

Comment: It's very complicated and, frankly, probably not worth the trouble of fully understanding it for most people and most situations.  If you need one to happen before the other, code it that way rather than relying on minutiae of the event sub-system implementations.  You can start by reading here: [Scheduling execution in node.js](https://rclayton.silvrback.com/scheduling-execution-in-node-js).

Comment: The messy part is that what runs first can be influenced by what type of event triggered your block of code to execute in the first place because that determines where node.js was in it's event loop when the code ran which determines what it does next.  Remember, I said it was complicated.  I will repeat.  If you really want `A()` to execute before `B()` then just code it so that you control it that way rather than relying on this level of event loop scheduling detail.

Comment: @Neil.Work - Your reference is for a browser.  node.js has its own `setImmediate()` implementation that does not have those warnings.

Comment: As a general advice, when dealing with asynchronous events **never** depend on some events happening before others - by the very nature they are asynchronous. This is true for js, device drivers (C or assembly), go, Python's Twisted framework, Java's Futures etc. The whole point of design patterns such as Streams, Promises, observers, monads etc, is to allow you to order the sequence you want to respond to events

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues on GitHub that reference this behavior. [A comment](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/25788#issuecomment-128869483) on one of [these issues](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/25788) does a pretty good job at explaining why it happens:

> What happens with the code you mentioned is that the timer and the
>   immediate are added, and then the libuv event loop starts. When it
>   starts, the libuv event loop first check for timers, and if the time
>   between when a timer was added and when the event loop starts is
>   greater than the timer's timeout value, then that timer will fire
>   before any immediate.

So basically, if you haven't yet entered the event loop, the callback in your `setTimeout` is going to get executed on the first tick. Otherwise, the `setImmediate` will get executed first.

As a demonstration, if you wrap a `setTimeout` and `setImmediate` in another `setTimeout`, the `setImmediate` gets executed first:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('setTimeout executed!')
    }, 0);
    setImmediate(function() {
        console.log('setImmediate executed!')
    });
}, 20);
```

Comment: This is an excellent example of what I said in my comment above about the order varying depending upon how the original code was triggered (and therefore where in the event loop cycle the interpreter was when the code originally ran).